# Symfony category and subcategory widget in one widget

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, widget, symfony-forms

I have two relations in my schema, product with many subcategory and product with many category. So I can make in my **productForm.class.php**

```
$this->widgetSchema['subcategory_list'] = new  sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Subcategory', 'add_empty' => false, 'multiple' => true,'expanded'   => true));

$this->widgetSchema['category_list'] = new  sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Category', 'add_empty' => false, 'multiple' => true,'expanded'   => true));
```

And it is work. But I need to make  for example:

**category1**

subcategory 1 , subcategory2

**category2**

**category3**

subcategory3, subcategory4

And I need to make, that I can check category and subcategory.

Thank  you!

**Upd**

```
Product:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      canUpdate: true
      fields: [name]
      builder: [myTools, StripText]
    I18n:
      fields: [name,description,shortbody,meta_keywords,meta_description]
  columns:
    partner_id:           { type: integer() }
    active:               { type: boolean, default: 0, notnull: false }
    name:                 { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    shortbody:            { type: string(500), notnull: true }
    description:          { type: string(), notnull: true }
    reference:            { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    code:                 { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    delivery_period:      { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    shipping_volume:      { type: string(100), notnull: true }    
    weight:               { type: string(100), notnull: true } 
    packing:              { type: string(100), notnull: true } 
    package_dimensions:   { type: string(100), notnull: true } 
    type_of_packaging:    { type: string(100), notnull: true } 
    video_url:            { type: string(100), notnull: false }
    meta_keywords:        { type: string(255) }
    meta_description:     { type: string(255) }
  relations:
    Subcategory:          { local: product_id , foreign: subcategory_id, refClass: ProductSubcategory } 
    Category:             { local: product_id , foreign: category_id, refClass: ProductCategory } 
    Partner:              { local: partner_id , foreign: id, onDelete: CASCADE }

ProductSubcategory:
  connection: doctrine
  columns:
    subcategory_id:  { type: integer(), primary: true}
    product_id:      { type: integer(), primary: true }
  relations:
    Product:         {  onDelete: CASCADE,local: product_id, foreign: id }
    Subcategory:     {  onDelete: CASCADE,local: subcategory_id, foreign: id }

ProductCategory:
  connection: doctrine
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer(), primary: true}
    product_id:   { type: integer(), primary: true }
  relations:
    Product:             {  onDelete: CASCADE,local: product_id, foreign: id }
    Category:            {  onDelete: CASCADE,local: category_id, foreign: id }

Category:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      canUpdate: true
      fields: [name]
      builder: [myTools, StripText]
    I18n:
      fields: [name]
  columns:
      name:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }

Subcategory:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      canUpdate: true
      fields: [name]
      builder: [myTools, StripText]
    I18n:
      fields: [name]
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer() }
    name:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Category: { onDelete: CASCADE,local: category_id , foreign: id }
```

**ANSWER**

I make it manual. I get from cache file _form.php and rewrite it, add category and subcategory checkbox. Than I make some changes in action class(manual set and delete subcategories and categories). I use code from answer, so I check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/06

**UPDATED:**

you can simply in template:

```
$categories = CategoryTable::getInstance()->findAll();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
   echo $category->getName();
   $subcategory = SubcategoryTable::getInstance()->findBy('category_id', $category->getId());
   foreach($subcategory as $sub){
      echo $sub->getName();
   }
}
```

this should working ok, but this isnt correctly programming

Comment: show me your schema.yml with category,subcategory and news(?)

Comment: where is relation between Category and Subcategory? how do you know which subcategory is children which category?